# Random forest gives a certain feature too much weight

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

I have run a random forest classifier with scikit-learn. And my dataset got 10 same types of features which I named as feature1, feature2 ... feature10. These features come from the same data source in random order, so each one of them should be as important as the others. However, after I examined the feature_importances of my model, I found one particular feature weights much higher than the others (which is feature10). I understand the model cannot recognize these features as the same type, so how can I handle this situation. Can I somehow tell the model these features are equally important?

Comment: Could you please provide a MWE? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: built-in feature importance in random forest is created based on features usage during tree building. in case of complex relationships between features it can show wrong importance. Such examples can be high colinearlity between features or high cardinality, check this post: https://mljar.com/blog/feature-importance-in-random-forest/